# Php preg_replace, regex pattern doesn't match

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to develop a basic template engine, so I have to use preg_replace so much. I've a problem about below subject:

```
$subject = "{%content%} %content%";
$pattern = '/matched_regex/';
$replace = 'OK';
echo preg_replace($pattern,$replace,$subject);
```

and the output must be like this:

```
{%content%} OK
```

in other words it will be just matched with `%content%`

What should I do regex pattern?

Comment: I've tried this
$pattern = '/[^{]%\s*(.*?)\s*%[^}]/';

Comment: and this $pattern = '/{{0}?%\s*(.*?)\s*%}{0}/';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will match only `%content%` that is not following an `{` or is at the beginning of the subject string. Any character that was before the `%content%` is put back with the `\1` in the replacement string:

```
$subjects = [
    '{%content%} %content%',
    'Foo {%content%} bar %content% baz',
    'Foo{%content%}bar%content%baz',
    'Foo{%content%}bar%content%',
    '{%content%}%content%',
    '%content%{%content%}',
];

$replace = 'OK';
foreach ($subjects as $subject) {
    $pattern = '/(^|[^{])%content%/';
    echo preg_replace($pattern, '\1'.$replace, $subject), PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
{%content%} OK
Foo {%content%} bar OK baz
Foo{%content%}barOKbaz
Foo{%content%}barOK
{%content%}OK
OK{%content%}
```